# Version-controlling version-specific files

Tags: svn, version-control

Imagine an application with several released versions: V1.0, V1.1, and V1.2.

Now imagine one or more associated files that are version-specific, for example a user manual, a functional test suite, or some technical documentation. Ideally these files would be checked into version together with the application itself, so that it's easy to view and/or check out all the files relating to a specific version (e.g. to run the functional tests as part of a continuous build).

The problem is that any of these files might need to be updated even when the code is not. For example, we might discover errors in the V1.0 user manual that we want to fix for the benefit of customers still using that version. Or we might want to improve the coverage of the functional tests for V1.2 in order to discover bugs in that version before our customers do. Having changed those files accordingly, how do we commit them to version control? We're not releasing new versions of the software, just new versions of the files that go with them.

FWIW, we're using SVN.

Comment: It's almost like we need a three-dimensional version control system, where each code revision (i.e. node in the development tree) can itself have a branch for non-code files like those mentioned above...

Comment: What source control system are you using currently?

Comment: @Andrew: CLearcase is capable of such "3d" version control. It's a bit of an expensive beast, though.

Comment: In git, I would commit to the oldest branch and merge upwards, if possible. So change in v1.0, merge -> v1.1 then merge -> v1.2

Answer (score 6):

If everything relating to the project (documentation, functional tests) is copied (branched) when you release a new version, then all you have to do is update what you need to on the branch.

Typically this is done by merging from trunk, but it may not be if the change is specific to that version.

Comment: This is really the best way to approach this. Branches can even be used to add bug fixes while trunk is used to continue forward with development.

Comment: Typically we do the bug fix in the release branch and propagate it back to the trunk; this is much easier than merging from the trunk and cherry-picking what changes are needed.  I believe this is also the best practice put forth by version control type folks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem.

You commit as often as you like; what you're talking about is being able bring down different revisions of the given documents, and condense them into a single "release". It's quite possible to do this, depending on how you build. You can just update specific things to specific versions (at least in SVN you can, I can't speak for other systems [say, visual source safe (god help you)]).

If it is SVN you're using, you may also be interested in the 'tagging' feature.

Comment: A tag is supposed to be read-only, if you want to update V1.0 but trunk is V1.1, you need a branch of V1.0 to update, otherwise you risk pulling V1.1 stuff into V1.0.